# What is the name of this basic removable joint?

Tags: plywood, knockdown

[image: joint]
I want to try using this basic joint to make removable legs for a table, but what's it called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proportions are a little unusual but this is a form of *bridle joint*. A bridle joint (also called an open mortise and tenon) is most commonly employed to join two boards at 90° at their ends, i.e. as a corner joint, but can be used anywhere along the span of one of the boards as here, and as in this example:

[image: Leg bridle joints]

<sup>Note the orientation of the joint relative to the wood thickness.</sup>

**Safety**
Since these are intended to be legs for a table, even if cut accurately so the joint is a tight fit this would not have the greatest stability. And as you can expect the fit to loosen with use (due to compression and wear) the stability will get poorer over time with assembly and disassembly.

If you need to put this table up and take it down regularly, and especially if it needs to take some weight, I think you'd be better off going with one of the (numerous) established designs for knock-down tables. Plywood is ideal for some of them, taking advantage of its dimensional stability.

*Nomadic table* would be another useful search term.